# Is there a way to achieve a glow effect on a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, glow

I need to do this effect on a layout like the following :

[image]

I tried with gradient on a shape, shadows, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable , https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter

or even some libraries: https://github.com/SanojPunchihewa/GlowButton

But it always depends on a bitmap or on a button

What I have for the moment is my drawable and layout :

Shape drawable with strokes :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="22.5dp"/>
    <padding android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:bottom="3dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Layout :

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_selections"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_accent_light_stroke"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:tag="perso_button_rounded_accent_light">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_selections_line_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:tag="perso_text_view_accent"
                        android:text="Ma Commande"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlueLight"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
                        android:shadowRadius="90">

                    </Button>


                </LinearLayout>
```

The library is  rendering like following which is pixelating

[image]

Do you have an idea on how to do this effect ? (I want to do it programmatically, not using an image)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Search for ColorMatrix GLOW effect.